# prove $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^{-p} \ge n (\bar x)^{-p} $

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Can we prove that the sum of negative powers is larger than n times of the negative power of the mean? i.e. with $x_i > 0$,  $p \geq 0$,

$$\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^{-p} \ge n (\bar x)^{-p} $$ in which $\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} x_i $ is the mean.

Numerical tests show this inequality holds. Is there a theoretical proof of this inequality? Thanks!

Comment: This is true for $p\ge1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Comment: Your claim is not true.  For $p\in[-\infty,+\infty]$, suppose that $$M_p(x):=\left(\frac{1}{n}\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,x_i^p\right)^{\frac1p}$$ for $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$ (where $M_p(x):=0$ if $p<0$ and $x_i=0$ for some $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, $M_0(x):=\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}$, $M_{-\infty}(x):=\min\limits_{i=1}^n\,x_i$, and $M_{+\infty}(x):=\max\limits_{i=1}^n\,x_i$).  The function $f:[-\infty,+\infty]\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $$f(p):=M_p(x)$$ is  nonincreasing.  It is strictly increasing if $x_i>0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$ is not true.

Comment: @Batominovski: thanks, you are right. I should limit the exponent to be negative. otherwise, it does not hold. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I guess you meant to write $x_i>0$ instead of $x_i\geq 0$ (as $x_i^{-p}$ is meaningless of $x_i=0$ and $p>0$).  Anyway, the inequality after the edit is true, and can be proved via the AM-GM Inequality.

Comment: @Batominovski: yes, it should not be zero.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: Hi Angina, I modified the question to limit the exponent to be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of expectations, your claim is $E(X^{-p})\ge(EX)^{-p}$. By Jensen's theorem, this follows if $p\ge0$ or $p\le-1$, since $(x^{-p})^{\prime\prime}=p(p+1)x^{-p-2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is what I'm looking for. Jensen's inequality is the very thing behind it.